# How to change the windows phone user agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm making a web browser control and my code to change the user agent doesn't seem to work.

```
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(textBox1.Text, null, null, "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.7; zh-cn; MB525 Build MIUI) UC AppleWebKit 534.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari 534.31", UriKind.Absolute));
```

I like this user agent because it seems to load pages in a mobile format easier to use.

Comment: How is it not-seeming-to-work? Is there an error message or is your server reporting a different value is sent?

Comment: Visual studio says that navigate can't have 5 arguments. is the code written wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. This is what you've got (formatted):

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(
    new Uri(
        textBox1.Text,
        null,
        null,
        "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.7; zh-cn; MB525 Build MIUI) UC AppleWebKit 534.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari 534.31",
        UriKind.Absolute
    )
);
```

This is what it should be (using this as the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636(v=vs.105).aspx )

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(
    new Uri(
        textBox1.Text
    ),
    null,
    "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.7; zh-cn; MB525 Build MIUI) UC AppleWebKit 534.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari 534.31"
);
```